# PHP form submission to multiple emails

Tags: php, forms

I've got a php web form that I'm trying to use on a contact us page. Everything is working as intended except for the ability to send the successful submissions to multiple email addresses. I've tried the following:

```
$targetEmail = 'email@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com';
```

as well as putting the $targetEmail in an array:

```
$targetEmail = array(
  'Email1' => 'email@gmail.com',
  'Email1' => 'email2@gmail.com',
);
```

but it never submits to both addresses. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The full code can be found below

```html
<?php
 //****************************************
 //edit here
 $senderName = 'Contact Form';
 $senderEmail = 'admin@gmail.com';
 $targetEmail = 'email1@gmail.com';
 $messageSubject = 'Contact Us Form';
 $redirectToReferer = false;
 $redirectURL = 'http://www.website.com/thankyou.html';
 //****************************************

 // mail content
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 // prepare message text
 $messageText = 'Name: '.$name."\n".
     'Email: '.$email."\n";

 // send email
 $senderName = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($senderName) . "?=";
 $messageSubject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($messageSubject) . "?=";
 $messageHeaders = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">\r\n"
    . "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"
    . "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

 if (preg_match('/^[_.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/',$targetEmail,$matches))
 mail($targetEmail, $messageSubject, $messageText, $messageHeaders);

 // redirect
 if($redirectToReferer) {
  header("Location: ".@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'#sent');
 } else {
  // header("Location: ".$redirectURL);
  header("Location: http://www.website.com/thankyou.html");
 }
?>
```

Comment: `$targetEmail = 'email@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate out the email addresses WITHIN the string with the comma:

```
 $targetEmail = 'email@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com';
```

With the array, you're attempting to create two entries with the same key, so it overwrites it. Instead, use different keys:

```
$targetEmail = array(
  'Email1' => 'email@gmail.com',
  'Email2' => 'email2@gmail.com',
);
```